# writing binop to work with int and floats

Tags: haskell, typechecking

I have a parser that I am working on.  Without getting into the all the details, I want a function that will add two numeric values do:

```
add [VFloat a, VFloat b] = return $ VFloat (a + b)
add [VInt   a, VFloat b] = return $ VFloat (fromInteger a + b)
add [VFloat a, VInt   b] = return $ VFloat (a + fromInteger b)
add [VInt   a, VInt   b] = return $ VInt   (a + b)
add [_,_] = throwError "Currently only adding numbers"
add _ = throwError "Arity Error: Add takes 2 arguments"
```

Cool, works great.  Now I want the same function for `-`,`*`,`/`,`<`,`>`,`==`,etc...

So I factor out the `+` operator and go to pass in an operator `op :: Num a => a->a->a` right?

Well not quite.  If I just replace the `+` with `'op'` the type-checker tells me that op is actually `Double -> Double -> Double` based on the first three versions and therefore it cannot be applied to `Integer`s in the fourth version.

Two questions:

1. How do I write `binop :: Num a => (a->a->a) -> [Value]-> EvalM Value` so that it can handle both VInt and VFloat?
2. What is the proper name for the situation I am facing so I can Google the answer next time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [higher rank types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types), basically the type you want is

```
 binop :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> [Value] -> EvalM Value
```

But what you have is

```
 binop :: forall a. Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> [Value] -> EvalM Value
```

Do you see the difference? With the first function, the operator is actually polymorphic within the function, it says "Given a function that takes any `Num a` of type `a -> a -> a` ...". The second one says, "For all `a`, given a function from a single arbitrary `a -> a -> a` ...".

Luckily GHC supports higher rank types,

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

...
binop :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> [Value] -> EvalM Value
binop (+) [VFloat a, VFloat b] = return $ VFloat (a + b)
binop (+) [VInt   a, VFloat b] = return $ VFloat (fromInteger a + b)
binop (+) [VFloat a, VInt   b] = return $ VFloat (a + fromInteger b)
binop (+) [VInt   a, VInt   b] = return $ VInt   (a + b)
binop  _  [_,_] = throwError "Currently only adding numbers"
binop  _  _     = throwError "Arity Error: Add takes 2 arguments"
```

However the type inferencer doesn't do so hot with higher rank types, so you will likely have to add explicit signatures.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably you'd have a function like

```
binop :: Num a => (a -> a -> a) -> [Value] -> EvalM Value
binop op [VFloat a, VFloat b] = return $ VFloat (a `op` b)
...
binop op [VInt a, VInt b] = return $ VInt (a `op` b)
```

The problem is that you're forcing `binop` to work with in the first case *and* the second case without doing any kind of type conversion.  In one case you say that *the same operator* has to accept `Double` and `Integer`.  You can get around this easily be converting the last case to `Double` then back to an `Integer`, but you could also lose precision doing this, and it probably isn't what you want to do if you're going to treat `/` as integer division.

Instead, what you can do is use `RankNTypes` to specify that your operator must work for *all* `Num` types at once, not just one at a time.

```
binop :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> [Value] -> EvalM Value
binop op [VFloat a, VFloat b] = return $ VFloat $ a `op` b
binop op [VInt a,     VInt b] = return $ VInt $ a `op` b
binop op [VFloat a,   VInt b] = return $ VFloat $ a `op` fromIntegral b
binop op [VInt a,   VFloat b] = return $ VFloat $ fromIntegral a `op` b
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this with [Rank2Types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types), which will still allow inference to work in most scenarios.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

data Value = VFloat Double | VInt Integer

op :: (forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a) -> [Value] -> EvalM Value
op (#) args = case args of
  [VInt a, VInt b]     -> return $ VInt $ a # b
  [VInt a, VFloat b]   -> return $ VFloat $ fromIntegral a # b
  [VFloat a, VInt b]   -> return $ VFloat $ a # fromIntegral b
  [VFloat a, VFloat b] -> return $ VFloat $ a # b
```

Also be careful since `Num` is not general enough to express operators like `(/)` which will need `Fractional`.

Comment: Currently Rank2Types is just a [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020428/are-there-any-advantages-of-using-rank2types-in-favor-of-rankntypes) for RankNTypes

Comment: Thanks for the warning about `(/)` I can had write a few of these corner cases.